# C# Selenium - Can't access image url in another tag

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to validate image on website however can't access the url of the image.
Most websites will have the image with a "src" tag however this website has the url imbedded in another tag.

Iv used `return driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("p-image__image--contain"));` to access the element and used `GetAttribute("style");` to access the image url. However the only information given was `background-position: center center;`

[html format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XulzM.png)

Comment: Please post code, not images of code.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `GetAttribute("style")`, it will only return whatever was in the actual `style` attribute on the element, but many CSS attributes are actually applied using `class` stylesheets or other ways.  So instead you should use the `GetCssValue` method, like so:

`element.GetCssValue("background-image")`

Answer (score 0):

`getCssValue();` will help in this case

```
WebElement img = driver.findElement(By.className('imgClass'));
String imgPath = img.getCssValue("background-image");
```

you will got full values in `imgPath`, Value like `url("imageURL")` then you need to use regex OR get values by slip function

I hope this scenario will help